# Asset Bundling: Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624

Tags: bundling

I am trying to bundle css and js on a sitecore 9.0.2 solution. I am getting the above run time error when the view calls the Styles.Render method. I am using Web.Optimizations 1.1.3 which is dependent on web grease 1.5.2. The webgrease DLL in my sandbox is version 1.5.2.14234.

What I have tried:

Added assembly binding to web.config

```
<assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
```

Added packes to packages.config

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Added namespace to views web config:

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
```

I also checked that the razor dll and binding was same as vanilla sitecore and I compared my configs and DLLS against a non-sitecore web app that I was able to get bundling working in easily.

Comment: Probably check your all projects in the solution and confirm it's using same version

Comment: Only one project is using web.optimization and webgrease

Comment: Have you tried enabling Fusion logging to see more details about why the binding is failing? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527249/1304050

Comment: Having the same problem. Disappointed to see this unanswered.